# How to know where Joomla database is?

Tags: joomla, connection

I took a project from someone else that is written with joomla. I don't work with joomla.

How to find its database and how to add it to project?
 This is part of configuration.php :

```
public $user = 'png';
public $password = 'pass';
public $db = 'db_name';
```

I checked configuration.php and I created a database (without their tables) with the same name ('db_name') in phpmyadmin but again, the database connection error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the Joomla installation, it creates the configuration.php. If you're on your localhost, then your database is going to be "localhost".

I'd recommend double-checking PHPMyAdmin to verify the database name, username, and password. When I run my localhost, my configuration.php usually looks like this:

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root;
public $password = '';
public $db = 'joomla';
public $dbprefix = 'jos_';
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need the host name. The relevant lines in the configuration.php file are as follows:

```
public $host = 'host_name';
public $user = 'db_user;
public $password = 'db_password*';
public $db = 'db_name';
public $dbprefix = 'db_prefix';
```

Set `public $host = 'localhost';` and you'll also need to restore the Joomla database tables to the database before being able to make a successful connection.

You can export the database tables from the original location and import them into the new database using phpMyAdmin or similar. Alternatively, you could use Akeeba backup to back up the files and database on the original location and then restore these to your localhost using Kickstart. Akeeba Backup and Kickstart are free.

Comment: yes I'm opening my project in localhost but there is the database connection error.